# How to control camel threads per destination route (activemq topic)?

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic, apache-servicemix

I'm using servicemix and camel to publish to some activemq topics:

```
from("vm:all").recipientList().simple(String.format("activemq:topic:%s.%s.%s.%s.%s.%s","${header.type}", ...
```

but a new producer thread gets created per topic, any idea how I can control that?

Edit1:

Actually I realized that I was creating too many topics and should you Selectors instead: http://www.andrejkoelewijn.com/blog/2011/02/21/camel-activemq-topic-route-with-jms-selector/

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical scenario is that Camel is using JMSTemplate to fire messages to ActiveMQ. That means it creates a new [producer each time](http://activemq.apache.org/jmstemplate-gotchas.html). Actually, it creates a new connection, session and producer per message. That is usually no issue except performance wise.

This is typically handled by org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory which caches connections, sessions and producers for you. However, depending on your configuration, it might create "some" producers initially, but they will be reused.

Check your Connection Factory settings in activemq-broker.xml and make sure you grab the PooledConnectionFactory.

Comment: I do use the PooledConnectionFactory, but for each topic (not some)  that I publish to, a pool of thread is created...

Comment: Well, a pooled session does not create a producer per destination. It creates one producer per session. The number of sessions created is configurable.